# Correct pronunciation of either?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm doing subtitles for some videos on Youtube. I heard the words *either* and *neither* spoken in two different ways by the same person. Written it could be:

- `ee-ther` versus `i-ther` or
- `n-ee-ther` versus `n-i-ther`

Is there a rule for which pronunciation to use? Or is it just a matter of birth/taste/location?

Comment: No. They'd both be spelled _either_, no matter whether they were pronounced /'iðər/ or /'ayðər/; ditto _neither_. Trying to account for accent differences gets complicated for stuff that hasta be read fast. Stick with the spelling.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point for the subtitles. But as you might have noticed: I'm not trying to enter accent differences to the subtitles. I just wanted to understand why it's sometimes spoken one way and sometimes another because I'm curious about the english language. :-)

Comment: It's something of a socioeconomic marker any more, plus it's been immortalized in a Cole Porter song. Otherwise, it's individual choice and habit.

Comment: I guess this goes actually a little deeper than I wanted... But it's partly the same question. Thanks.

Comment: This has been covered before, several times over in fact. Please [use the site search](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=pronunciation%20either) before asking. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As with many of life's most vexing questions, the answer to this one was composed by the Gershwin and [delivered by Ella Fitzgerald and Louis Armstrong](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2oEmPP5dTM):

> You say either and I say either.
>   You say neither and I say neither.
>   Either, either. Neither, neither.
>   Let's call the whole thing off.

Comment: Okay, so it seems to be a matter of habit or accent or coloration of the language a person is using. But is it somehow weird if you'd switch between both ways to pronunce it? I guess this doesn't happen if you're a native speaker, does it?

Comment: Most people stick to one, but I have heard people switch and people who pronounce "either" and "neither" differently, and people who use one pronunciation for "either way" and the other for "either this or that".

Comment: A comedian once got a lot of laughs out of this song by pretending to miss the point and pronouncing both instances of each word the same way. "You say ee-ther and I say ee-ther..."